# $query->where in many to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In my controller I setup two filters one for category (has-one relationship)
and one for shop (many to many relationship)

```
public function products($filter = NULL, $key = NULL)
{
    $query = Product::query();
    $query = $query->where('status', '=', 1);
    if ($filter === 'category') {
        $cat = Category::where('slug', '=', $key)->select('id')->firstOrFail();
        $query = $query->where('category_id', '=', $cat->id);
    }
    if ($filtro === 'shop') {
        $shop = Shop::where('slug', '=', $key)->select('id')->firstOrFail();
        // HOW TO ADD HERE A WHERE IN MANY TO MANY RELATIONSHIP*
    }
    $products = $query->whereNotNull('startdate')->with('shops', 'categories')->orderby('startdate')->get();
```

*HOW TO ADD to the query A WHERE IN MANY TO MANY RELATIONSHIP only if "shop" filter are set?

Comment: Show me your table structure first. And what results from your expecting?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `whereHas()` method like this:

```
$query->whereHas('shops', function($q) use($shop) {
   $q->where('id', $shop->id); 
});
```

Define the `shops` relationship in the `Product` model to make this work.